Multiple Rasters as environment in Netlogo
I have different rasters in a Rasterbrick object. They reflect the habitat suitability of species through time. How can I incorporate these rasters into an Agent-Based Model in Netlogo and, with each time step, the environment where agents operate is updated with the next raster layer?

Generally for GIS tasks you can use the GIS extension. It allows you to apply rasters to your NetLogo world (eg. using gis:apply-raster).
